# Application for UK Visa - Work permit

Tags: uk, qatar, visa-cancellation

I have worked in for 2.5 year in Qatar and return to Srilanka in 2011. My work permit visa is cancelled by the employer when I'm leaving from Qatar.

Now I need to go to UK for an official purpose. So, I have applied for Work permit visa for 3 months.

Does my previous visa cancellation cause any issues when I'm applying for UK visa?

Comment: No, if you acquitted yourself to the visa's terms and conditions, there's no problem. The UK also cancels work permits in the same way.